# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toDataURL' of null

Tags: html, canvas, save, image

I met this message of error while trying to save an image which has been generating using html2canvas.

So I wrote this code :

```
<div id"mycanvas">
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <div id="container3" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>

 </page> 


<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
    </script>
```

Even If the image rendered is in the cache and good generated using html2canvas I don't know how to save it.

This code don't seems to be wrong but it displays to me this message of error.

So I'm a bit lost.

Here are the errors messages:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toDataURL' of null export-graphic-stat_employee.php:241
html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images Core.js:18
html2canvas: Preload: Finding images Core.js:18
html2canvas: Preload: Done. Core.js:18
html2canvas: start: images: 0 / 0 (failed: 0) Core.js:18
Finished loading images: # 0 (failed: 0) Core.js:18
html2canvas: Renderer: Canvas renderer done - returning canvas obj Core.js:18
Screenshot created in 167 ms<br /> Core.js:18
```

Receive all my utmost respect.

Kind regards.

S.P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an equals sign here;

```
<div id"mycanvas">
```

...which means your...

```
document.getElementById("mycanvas");
```

will return null.

Calling `null.toDataURL("image/png");` is what is giving you the error message.

EDIT: If you want to actually use toDataURL, that method only works on an actual canvas element and you're trying to use it on a `div`. Instead, remove the id on the `div` and either add;

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400" > </canvas>
```

or use the actual canvas id from the canvas generated by HTML2Canvas to have an actual canvas element to work with.

Comment: Oh you are right. But now it displays to me Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'toDataURL'

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The weird part of this is that Html2canvas display to me an image and when I try to save it it is a blank image white image.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski `html2canvas` creates a canvas element, so that's the one you want to use, not the div. Unsure how to get or set the element's `id` though so you can access it.

Comment: I've change to canvas the div. But the output is a blank image

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski You're generating an image with html2canvas, but how are you putting it into the page? You'll need to save that canvas (ie know the id of that one)

Comment: Actually it displays itself alone into to page. Using a javascript http://jsfiddle.net/V4x4x/